# Precedence of clojure protocols in another namespace

Tags: clojure, namespaces, clojure-protocol

In a project using `clojure.java.jmx`, I was extending it's `Destract` protocols `objects->data` function  to transform more of the JMX data structures returned from calls or metadata queries into plain clojure data structures.

When I was done with the individual data structures, it should have been possible to do a `(walk/prewalk jmx/objects->data (jmx/operations "java.lang:type=Threading"))`.

However, in the `Destract` protocol there's an [implementation](https://github.com/clojure/java.jmx/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/java/jmx.clj#L143) of the `objects->data` function for the type `clojure.lang.Associative` that would mean maps would be processed incorrectly.
I could add an implementation for `clojure.lang.IPersistentMap` in my namespace, but since `clojure.lang.Associative` is also an interface for maps this would not work.

I ended up having to fork `clojure.java.jmx` because of it. If there would be a way to change preference, or retract a protocol for a type within another namespace I wouldn't have had to.

Is there a way to prevent `clojure.lang.Associative` taking precedence over  `clojure.lang.IPersistentMap` in the protocol ?

If there isn't, is it possible to retract a protocol for a type in another namespace ? Would it even be possible to implement it in regard to the way protocols are compiled into Java interfaces ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It should work

Are you sure that providing your own implementation for `clojure.lang.IPersistentMap` won't work? It works in my REPL session. It even works when I just override the default implementation for `clojure.lang.Associative`:

```
user=> (ns ns1)
;;=> nil

ns1=> (defprotocol IPrintable (prnt [this]))
;;=> IPrintable

ns1=> (extend-protocol IPrintable clojure.lang.Associative (prnt [this] (str "clojure.lang.Associative " this)))
;;=> nil

ns1=> (ns ns2)
;;=> nil

ns2=> (ns1/prnt {:a 1})
;;=> "clojure.lang.Associative {:a 1}"

ns2=> (extend-protocol ns1/IPrintable clojure.lang.Associative (prnt [this] (str "My custom impl for clojure.lang.Associative " this)))
;;=> nil

ns2=> (ns1/prnt {:a 1})
;;=> "My custom impl for clojure.lang.Associative {:a 1}"
```

It also works in a [sample project](https://github.com/pbzdyl/so-36312830).

You must remember to `require` the namespace where you `extend-protocol` if it's not loaded transitively by another namespace. It's important that your `extend-protocol` will be loaded after the one you would like to override.

Internally `extend-protocol` or `extend-type` modify a special map attached to protocol's metadata where it `assoc`s a given type with a function implementation. If there was an existing entry for a given type it will be overridden. Thus the order in which `extend-*` are executed is important.

#### When it won't work

When an object implements an interface or a protocol directly (e.g. inline in `defrecord`) you cannot override the implementation (continued REPL session):

```
ns2=> (defrecord SomeData []
        ns1/IPrintable (prnt [this] "I'm SomeData"))
;;=> ns2.SomeData

ns2=> (ns1/prnt (SomeData.))
;;=> "I'm SomeData"

ns2=> (extend-protocol ns1/IPrintable SomeData (prnt [this] "Custom impl " this))
;;=> IllegalArgumentException class ns2.SomeData already directly implements interface ns1.IPrintable for protocol:#'ns1/IPrintable  clojure.core/extend (core_deftype.clj:775)
```

Comment: The problem is that the Associative function takes precedence over the IPersistentMap one when a map is encountered, since a map is both. Thanks to this answer I did find out I could overwrite the Associative function with one in my namespace calling identity, making it a noop. A bit hacky, but in the end effectively the same as removing it.